# Jenkins pipeline on EC2 to push images in ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cli

I have EC2 in my Dev environment and i am building CICD in this EC2 and pushing images to ECR.

I am using below commands in my Jenkinsfile to push image to ECR.

```
 sh '$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)'
 sh 'docker push 572205960066.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mh367/dc:latest'
```

Now i have been asked to use same EC2 to create pipeline for production environment which is different AWS account.I understand that i can create a cross-account role to get required permission to push images.

But my concern is how to create a docker login url for production account in Dev account's EC2 ? As in "aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1" we don't specify account so it will always generate for dev account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws ecr` cli command has an option for specifying the registry-id with `--registry-ids` option. That could be used to enable temporary access in order to be able to push/pull multiple ECR registries

More details can be found at:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html

Comment: does it reques a cross account role ?

Comment: yes, you do need to authorize the requests with cross account roles